Why can't I remove a widget family from iOS app
While noodling around with widgets I added a .systemMedium type. I have not been able to make it look good so I removed it from my code in three places

The PreviewProvider struct only has one for .systemSmall
the Widget struct says supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
The ....WidgetEntryView doesn't reference it any more

and yet, when I build and deploy the app I get this error in Xcode. I've deleted the app and done a fresh install, but something is still insisting that it wants a systemMedium widget even though I have removed it. Can anyone tell me if there is somewhere else in my code keeping a list of widget sizes I used to offer?
"Request widget family (systemMedium) is not supported by this widget kind"



SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget 'com.test.Weather-Widget' error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.apple.springboard" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace)., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x48c01a880 {Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=3 "**Request widget family (systemMedium) is not supported by this widget kind** (Weather_Widget)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request widget family (systemMedium) is not supported by this widget kind (Weather_Widget)}}, 


It's a scheme setting
Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme (select the widget one) > Run
Under 'Arguments' > 'WidgetKit Environment', change Family to .systemSmall
